# Twilio call connection issue

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

When call connects or ringing twilio shows second. Even when ends the call after receiving twilio sends duration in a callback from when call connects. But it should when call is received.
Can anyone let me know the solution?

I have created an issue on [github](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-php/issues/7) php quickstart by twillio.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I am not sure what you are asking here. What do you expect to happen and what is happening? Be as detailed as you can and share code if it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For to only receive the "connected" callback when the call has been answered by the receiver,use `answerOnBridge` flag in your verb.